# Can I use a specific date format for CONKY?

Tags: locale, language-support, conky

I'm playing with conky and I'm a Chinese user, so my locale of system is something like `zh_CN.UTF-8` conky seems will use the system API to show the date, but I don't want conky to show date in Chinese, and I really don't want to change the locale of whole system,
so, is there any solution for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation the 'time' variable in conky takes an optional format-string. From the conky variables page i got this.

`time (format) Local time, see man strftime to get more information about format`

ie `${time %H:%M}` will output the time in 24-hour format.

So do a `man strftime` to find out the correct format string for your needs.

For more information on conky variables take a look at this: [conky variables](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html)

Comment: thanks,but according to the man strftime,the output always according to the current locale.so finally I used some IF to do so.like this:http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/6110/displaying-the-date-in-conky-in-a-different-language/